# Сортировка объектов внутри списка ArrayList по значению одного поля данных этих объектов

Tags: android, java

Имеется массив:

```
List<Object> listZakazchik = new ArrayList<>();
```

в нём лежат объекты (количество динамическое):

```
new Object(String id, String avatar, String name, int rating)
```

у которых, к примеру rating = 50, rating = 95, rating = 75, rating = 100 ...

Как я могу отсортировать внутри листа эти объекты (либо создать новый лист), чтобы они в нём были по убыванию данных rating (100, 95, 75, 50)?

Вопрос сложнее: когда будут отсортированы объекты в порядке убывания поля int rating, нужно чтобы дальше шли объекты по значению поля String name /кириллица (если rating уже равен 0)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class MyComparator implements Comparator<Obj> {

        @Override
        public int compare(Obj o1, Obj o2) {
            return Integer.compare(o1.getRating(), o2.getRating());
        }

}
Collections.sort(list, new MyComparator ());
```

У тебя должен быть геттер того свойства, по которому ты сортируешь.
Если я не угадал с порядком - поменяй местами `о1` и `о2` в методе `Integer.compare()`.

Comment: .compare //Call requires API level 19 :((((
Рекомендуемый минимум для разработки 2015 - API level 14
Есть что-нибудь подобное для 14?

Comment: Странно, протестировал на 4.3 (API 18) - работает...
Вы верно подметили, поменяв местами o1 и o2 - сортирует по убыванию (иначе - по возрастанию).

Answer (score 2):

Реализовать в классе интерфейс `Comparable`:

```
public class MyClass implements   Comparable<MyClass>{
    [...]
    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyClass other) {
      if(this.rating > other.rating)
        return 1;
      if(this.rating < other.rating)
        return -1;
      return 0;
    }
}
```

А потом сама сортировка `Collections.sort(listZakazchik);`

Comment: comparabe НЕ подходит для сравнения объектов по некоторым параметрам. Он обязан использовать те поля, которые используются при расчёте HashCode объекта.

Comment: @argamidon не обязан

Comment: представляю баттхерд юзера, когда он поместит свой класс в TreeSet/TreeMap  с таким вот методом

Comment: @argamidon у вас юзеры имеют доступ к исходному коду вашего приложения?